# spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams consumer shuts down when RuntimeException occurs

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams consumer stops and goes into EMPTY state when exception occur on consumer. I want to test retry mechanism but it is not working as expected. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_error_handling). No message sent to dlq. Any ideas?

```
springBootVersion=3.2.4
springDependencyManagerVersion=1.1.4
springCloudVersion=2023.0.0
```

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams'
```

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CashbackBoosterProcessor {


    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, String>> processPosCashbackBooster() {

        return event -> event
                .mapValues(v -> {
                    if (true) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Testing of retry mechanism");
                    }
                    return v;
                });
    }
}
```

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: processPosCashbackBooster

    stream:
      bindings:
        processPosCashbackBooster-in-0:
         destination: input-topic
         consumer:
           concurrency: 2
           max-attempts: 3

        processPosCashbackBooster-out-0:
          destination: output-topic

      kafka:
        streams:
          bindings:
            processPosCashbackBooster-in-0:
              consumer:
                enable-dlq: true
                dlq-name: input-dlq
                configuration:
                  application.id: ${spring.application.name}-input-group
          binder:
            deserialization-exception-handler: sendtodlq
```

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [demo-8ed02931-b9d7-4743-a741-627001eb74de] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_ERROR
o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [demo-8ed02931-b9d7-4743-a741-627001eb74de-StreamThread-1] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [demo-8ed02931-b9d7-4743-a741-627001eb74de-StreamThread-1] Shutting down unclean
o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [demo-8ed02931-b9d7-4743-a741-627001eb74de-StreamThread-1] Informed to shut down
org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [demo-8ed02931-b9d7-4743-a741-627001eb74de] Shutting down 1 stream threads
o.a.k.s.processor.internals.StreamTask   : stream-thread [demo-8ed02931-b9d7-4743-a741-627001eb74de-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Suspended from RUNNING
o.a.k.s.p.internals.RecordCollectorImpl  : stream-thread [demo-8ed02931-b9d7-4743-a741-627001eb74de-StreamThread-1] stream-task [0_0] Closing record collector dirty
o.a.k.s.processor.internals.StreamTask   : stream-thread [demo-8ed02931-b9d7-4743-a741-627001eb74de-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Closed dirty
o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=demo-8ed02931-b9d7-4743-a741-627001eb74de-StreamThread-1-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
```

Comment: Based on docs, did you try exactly as written there instead of hyphenated and lowercase ?`deserializationExceptionHandler: sendToDlq`?

Comment: `deserializationExceptionHandler: sendToDlq` equals `deserialization-exception-handler: sendtodlq`.